# Subtracting a relation from a set

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, relations

I encountered the notation $A/ \sim_{N}$ where $(A, +)$ is an abelian group and $N \subset A$ is a subgroup. The relation $\sim_{N}$ on $A$ is defined by: $a\sim_{N}b \iff a-b \in N$.

What exactly does $A/ \sim_{N}$ mean? I know that a relation is a set of ordered pairs. So I would read it as "subtract the relation from the set $A$". But $A$ could for example be just a normal set with elements such as $\{a, b, c, ...\}$, etc. And the relation would consist of ordered pairs, for example, $\{(a, b), (b, c), ...\}$. So subtracting the relation from the set $A$ would just result in the set $A$, since the relation and $A$ have no elements in common, right?

Or do they mean $\frac{A}{\sim_N}$? Even so, I am still not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: This is a notation for the equivalence classes under the equivalence relation you described. So you are basically looking at a partition into disjoint subsets of the group $A$. This is a prelude to the definition (and replacement of the notation $A/ \sim_{N}$) of the quotient group $A/N$, since $A$ is abelian, $N$ is normal and one can impose an inherited group structure on $A/N$.

Comment: Oh alright, so the notation would be more akin to "divide A" rather than subtraction since you "divide" A into subsets (I am just trying to develop an intuition for the notation).

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\sim_{N}b \stackrel{(def.)}{\iff} a-b \in N$, then by $A/\sim_N$ it is meant the quotient set (group, in this case) "$A$ modulo $\sim_N$", namely:

$$A/\sim_N:=\{[a]_{\sim_N}, a\in A\} \tag 1$$

where:

\begin{alignat}{1}
[a]_{\sim_N} &:= \{b\in A\mid b\sim_N a\} \\
&=\{b\in A\mid b-a\in N\} \\
&=\{b\in A\mid b\in a+N\} \\
&= a+N \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

is the coset of $N$ by $a\in A$.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it. So since in this case, the relation is an equivalence relation, $A/{\sim_N}$ would just be the set of equivalence classes?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Kajice, yes that's it. Further, the fact that $A$ is an abelian group implies that $N$ is automatically normal in $A$, and hence $A/\sim_N$ is "more" that the set of equivalence classes, it's itself a group.